# Trying to write macro to read 24 months of data by yyyymmdd

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to write a macro to replace some current code.  The current code is like this:

```
data _null_;
 call symput('as_of_date_nbr1', put(intnx('month', today(),-1, 'E'), yymmddn.));
run;
%put &as_of_date_nbr1 yields 20210831
```

There is a data_null for each of 30 months.  That variable is then used in a data step where statement

```
where date = &as_of_date_nbr1
```

I want to write a macro where the variable as_of_date_nbr would take a macro variable from 1-30 and the intnx function would also take a macro variable from 1-30
So something like this if possible in a loop

```
data _null_;
call symput('as_of_date_nbr.&macvar, put(intnx('month,today(),-&macvar, 'E'), yyyymmddn.))
```

So far I'm not having any luck, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Why? What are you doing with these dates in the end. This is pretty trivial to be honest but I suspect it's also not needed.

Comment: The dates  will be used as dataset identifiers.  So I will be reading from one large dataset that has an index date in the form yyyymdd.  From that dataset I want to create separate datasets by date.

Comment: Why are you creating individual data sets? usually in SAS that is not the right approach unless you're literally running out of RAM somewhere? By group processing takes care of the different dates/months.

Comment: Because SAS doesn't allow partitions as far as I know

Comment: Usually it's not required in SAS since it processes data row by row, which is where BY group processing comes into play.

Comment: This paper covers why looping isn't super efficient https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start by trying to create a data set with the 30 dates needed.

```
data demo;
    do i=1 to 30;
        var_name=catt('month', put(i, z2. -l));
        var_value=intnx('month', today(), -1*i, 'e');
        format var_value yymmddn8.;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Once you're sure that's correct, you can add a CALL SYMPTUX line to create the macro variables.

```
    call symputx(var_name, put(var_value, yymmddn8.), 'g');
```

Depending on what you're doing overall, you may want to explore CALL EXECUTE. For examle if you were looping a macro with these values instead of call symputx you could use CALL EXECUTE() to just call the macro directly with the values instead.

So if you had a macro called %filter like this:

```
%macro filter(date_param);
   sas code
%mend;
```

You could call it instead as follows:

```
 call execute(catt('%filter_data(', put(var_value, yymmddn8.), ');'));
```

All together it would be something like this:

```
data demo;
    do i=1 to 30;
        var_name=catt('month', put(i, z2. -l));
        var_value=intnx('month', today(), -1*i, 'e');
        format var_value yymmddn8.;
        call symputx(var_name, put(var_value, yymmddn8.), 'g');
        *call execute(catt('%filter_data(', put(var_value, yymmddn8.), ');'));
        output;
    end;
run;

*check macro variables created properly;
%put &month01.;
%put &month15.;
%put &month30.;
```